# JPA: attribute is null when i want to access it after persisting an entity object from datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

currently i am reviewing a project. I have not much experience with `google app engine` (referred as **gae** after now) and JPA ( = Java Persistence API)

I am getting a strange error, that one of the attributes (which should be persisted) is `null` when i access it. So the program throws an `NullPointerException` ( **NPE** )

First, there are two entities (that matters) in this gae project

```
@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Car> cars;
    @ManyToMany
    private Map<String,Type> types;

    // constructor
    public Company(String name, Set<Car> cars) {
        setName(name);
        this.cars = cars;
        this.types = new HashMap<String, Type>();
    }

    // two of the methods
    public Collection<Type> getTypes() {
        return types.values(); // line 111 (see error notation)
    }
    public void addType(Type type) {
        if (type != null) {
            types.put(type.getName(), type);
        }
    }

    // other methods omitted
}

// =================

@Entity
public class Type {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;

    // other attributes + constructor + methods
}
```

Here below is a snippet how an instance of company class got created, and persisted into the Datastore

```
Company company = new Company(companyName, cars);
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
em.persist(company);
em.close();
loadData(companyName);
```

So the construction of a company occurs without problems. This class has a functionality to add types dynamically (if a new type got found, and a company buys a model of it, you simply have to add a new type...). That's why we didn't have included it in the constructor. Now, when we want to add types in the `loadData(...)` method, JVM throws a NPE. That has surprised us.

To verify it, i tried to check it myself, that i can access the `types`.

```
private void loadData(String companyName) {
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
    Company company = em.find(Company.class, companyName);

    // TODO delete
    System.out.println("number of cars: " + company.getCars().size()); // displays size correctly
    System.out.println("number of types: " + company.getTypes().size()); // error ! (see next code block)

}
```

But this throws also an error. Here is the output of the error:

```
... (omitted)
number of cars: 2
Nov 17, 2015 8:17:04 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@17f1292f{/,D:\workspace\RentalInGAE\war}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ds.gae.entities.Company.getTypes(Company.java:111)
    at ds.gae.listener.RentalServletContextListener.loadData(RentalServletContextListener.java:96)
    at ds.gae.listener.RentalServletContextListener.loadRental(RentalServletContextListener.java:71)
... // omitted
```

I don't understand why the `types` keeps being null, despite i have constructed a HashMap object for it in the constructor. I have however added a line to verify if the construct has worked well.

```
// in constructor 
this.carTypes = new HashMap<String, CarType>();
System.out.println("constructed, types is not null ? " +(carTypes != null)); // outputs: constructed, types is not null ? true
```

So, after the persistence and obtaining the object, `cars` could be found (see output: 2) but the `types` not ? The map object got constructed nicely in the constructor... I don't have a clue why it becomes null. Does someone have a clue ? And how should i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a second (parameterless) constructor in your class, which is used by Hibernate - otherwise Hibernate could not create your class.

See the [Requirements for Entity Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#bnbqb):

> The class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor. The class may have other constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, the error is still same. It appears that the map is not being able to be persisted into the datastore.

Comment: What do you mean with _still the same_? Do you mean that you have a no-argument constructor. In that case you should [add](./edit) that information to your question. And if you've got the feeling that the data is not _persisted_, you should check your database to ensure that.